# Как настроить поддомен на сайте?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Допустим есть сайт site.ru
Как можно настроить htaccess так, чтобы в подпапке site.ru/script лежала старая версия данного сайта и чтобы было доступно по адресу script.site.ru?
пытался сделать примерно так:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?script\.site\.ru$ [NC]   
#папка на которую будет происходить переадресация   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/script/
#сама переадресация
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ script/$1 [L]
```

но тогда адрес будет такой: site.ru/script
Как настроить адрес script.site.ru на сайте?
Также есть админка ispmanager, может там как-то можно настроить?

Comment: В панели добавьте поддомен и в apache/nginx добавьте его

Comment: @InDevX, можете скинуть ссылку на хотя-бы похожий пример, где настраивается apache/nginx? а также настройка поддомена

Comment: ещё мало опыта по настройке apache/nginx

Comment: [How do I add a subdomain in ISPManager Control Panel?](https://libyanspider.com/knowledge/how-to-create-subdomain-in-isp-manager/), [How to create subdomain with nginx server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-create-subdomain-with-nginx-server-in-the-same-droplet?answer=31225)

Comment: @InDevX, подскажите, проще создать поддомен как новый домен через ispmanager, или добавить его в существующий домен?

Comment: Проще не знаю, но, в любом случае, для создания нужны данные главного домена